# How to run Profiler (memory management) from Android Studio for a React Native project?

Tags: android, performance, react-native, android-studio, memory

I'm working almost exclusively from the CLI without really opening Android Studio much. Now, I'd like to run the Android profiler, but all of the buttons are greyed out. If I search for the "Profile" action and run it, I get a window for templates and debug configurations which is something I haven't had to use with React Native and can't find any documentation.

Here's my screen after tapping "Profile..." - thanks!
[image]

Comment: When you open your project select android folder. Not main folder

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this doesn't actually change anything, the screen and "profile" pop-up appears the exact same (I think Android Studio detects the android folder whether you open that or one level above either way)